# Simple present tense VS present perfect tense

Tags: tense

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> a) Amount has been paid to you as basic salary.
>
> b) Amount is paid to you as basic salary.

Further to my query

> A) He is appointed as Deputy Manager.
> B) He has been appointed as deputy Manager.